# ios apns not sending consistently to devices

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications, pyapns

Good day people!

I started having this problem last month when the registered devices on my app stopped receiving push notifications

At first I realized that it was because Apple dropped SSL v3 support so I performed a git pull of the pyapns update.

Push messages started sending properly again, but are not being received. The push server logs are returning few malformed payload errors, but the occurrence of a successfully sent notification is very low, and sometimes being sent in batches.

After rebuilding the push certificate, push messages started being sent on time, and successfully, but this only lasted for a few hours.

As of now, a direct push notification test request to my server is not even being delivered to test devices properly, which was not the case a few hours back.

This is my setup:

1. All push messages are queued via Resque.
2. Actual server pushing the payload is 'pyapns.'
3. Push server OS is Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS.
4. Upon checking logs on my service, Resque, and pyapns, I was very sure that I am successfully sending the payload to the Apple push servers. There are no malformed payload responses from APNS, but still, no messages.
5. Push certificate is recently updated and is being used by server running pyapns.
6. A quick peek at the server shows that a copy of Entrust CA Root Certificate is installed (as per requirement for TLS connections, [specified by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html)).

Can anyone help me in this problem? Thank you!

Comment: how do things stop working after few hours? did you change anything

Comment: I did not change anything, I was doing another round of tests a few hours after seeing that my devices are properly receiving the push messages. What happened was the subsequent tests returned no errors on pyapns twistd.log, but the devices are not receiving the messages.

Answer (score 0):

How did you

> I updated my push server application to use TLS instead.

PyAPNs should auto switch to TLS without any further configuration. Please refer to [PyAPNs TLS support](https://github.com/djacobs/PyAPNs/issues/95), it contains openssl test command as well :)

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant performed a git pull of the latest pyapns